# after uninstall protobuf, use protoc command, there still protoc :error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.12

Tags: ubuntu, protocol-buffers, uninstallation

I installed protobuf 3.2.0 from the source code in Ubuntu;
but now I　want to install a lower  version's protobuf , so I　use make uninstall

Then I verify if  protobuf is still in my computer, so I use protoc command;

the response is : 
protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Why after I　uninstall protobuf, there still this error message？ How can I　solve this？

Comment: Have you tried to apt-get purge?

Comment: Cause I installed with source code, so it can't solved by apt-get purge

Answer (score 0):

Some of the installed files need superuser access to remove, e.g. the binary file /usr/bin/protoc.

Try 'sudo make uninstall'